# How to access the same push id and not create a new one in the process in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to access the push id in firebase database but in the process i end up creating a new push id instead...

Here's my database = https://ibb.co/bVeRJd

When i try to access the already created push id and edit data inside that it just creates another push id and edits the data in there...

Code

```
        MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");
    MessageRecieverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name");
    user_message_key = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).push();
    message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();
```

Fetching and editing

```
 private void fetchSeen() {
    final DatabaseReference messageRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
    final DatabaseReference seenRef = messageRef.child(message_push_id).child("Seen");
    messageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                HashMap<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
                update.put("Seen", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                seenRef.updateChildren(update);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Storing Data

```
private void sendMessage() {
    String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Send Blank Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
        String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
        messageTextBody.put("Message", messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("Seen", "False");
        messageTextBody.put("Type", "Text");
        messageTextBody.put("Time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        messageTextBody.put("From", MessageSenderId);



        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);

        mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
                messageArea.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in the fetchSeen method the messagepushid is not the old message id which was declared in the onCreate but making its own push id and storing data... How do i solve this problem... Please help me out

Database -

```
{
    "Messages" : {
    "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
      "jEmeGEvUvJbqw6ZxyYV1rRJa74m2" : {
        "-LHY3rNyYEFKEvslnv1D" : {
          "From" : "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2",
          "Message" : "Hiii",
          "Seen" : "False",
          "Time" : 1531744319418,
          "Type" : "Text"
        },
        "-LHY3sSXalwgpVKlK90J" : {
          "From" : "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2",
          "Message" : "How are you",
          "Seen" : "False",
          "Time" : 1531744323801,
          "Type" : "Text"
        },
        "-LHY3wJFwXzJGwLzV11L" : {
          "Seen" : 1548656184
        }
      }
    },
    "jEmeGEvUvJbqw6ZxyYV1rRJa74m2" : {
      "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
        "-LHY3rNyYEFKEvslnv1D" : {
          "From" : "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2",
          "Message" : "Hiii",
          "Seen" : "False",
          "Time" : 1531744319418,
          "Type" : "Text"
        },
        "-LHY3sSXalwgpVKlK90J" : {
          "From" : "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2",
          "Message" : "How are you",
          "Seen" : "False",
          "Time" : 1531744323801,
          "Type" : "Text"
        },
        "-LHY3wJFwXzJGwLzV11L" : {
          "From" : "jEmeGEvUvJbqw6ZxyYV1rRJa74m2",
          "Message" : "Fine",
          "Seen" : "False",
          "Time" : 1531744339674,
          "Type" : "Text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: How do i do that then

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Look to my edited question please @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks for that. I now see 3 snippets of code, and find it hard to understand where the problem is. If it's about `user_message_key = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).push();`, then indeed the call to `push()` generates a new push ID each time. If you want to determine the push ID for an existing item, you will need to query for that item.

Comment: The problem is in the onCreate i have declared push.getKey... the same is used to sedn message in the sendmessage method but a new id is used to check the seen feature... can i i get the code for the query please?

Comment: I don't see any change to `message_push_id` between when you set it and when you read it. If it changes between those times, it must be in code you didn't share. I'd recommend searching your entire class for any time `message_push_id` sets set.

Comment: No... you didnt get my problem i guess... i declare the push.getkey in oncreate... i use that in my method to send message as shown in the sendmessage... but when i try to retrieve that sent message(Each message has a different unique id) instead of retrieving the existing message and changing its value.. it creating a new push id and setting its value... see in the database... 2 push ids contain the messagedata(posted through sendmessage method) one unique id has a child which says seen = Timestamp... which is not intented... i want the timestamp to come for the messagebody data... Got it?

Comment: Not really. There are a bit too many steps in here for me to understand. Maybe somebody else got it. Otherwise, I'd recommend looking at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which typically would be a single snippet of code.